# Android: Context Menu to Alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

What do i need to change to make this display into alert dialog?

```
@Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()) {
                case DELETE_ID:
                    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                    mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                    fillData();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
```

I'm a beginner in android so i still don't know how to implements some things. I want this to appear as alert dialog. Currently the user needs to longkeypress to activate the delete. However i want to prompt it as an alert dialog and have choices for the user to choose from if he wants to really delete it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case DELETE_ID do this:

```
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Confirm Delete")
        .setMessage("Do you want to delete this blank?")
        .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
            }
        })
        .setNeutralButton("Cancel", null) // don't need to do anything but dismiss here
        .create()
        .show();
```

You need to put the delete logic in the OK click listener.

Comment: It works fine thank you. I forgot to clear it up, I mean when the user long key pressed an item from the list the alert dialog is the one that'll display prompting if he wants to delete an item from the list.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to implement the following function. It will work.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
{
Log.e(LOGTAG, "Tao menu");
if(v == expList)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    //AdapterContextMenuInfo aInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    // We know that each row in the adapter is a Map
    //HashMap map =  (HashMap) simpleAdpt.getItem(aInfo.position);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(1, 1, 1, "Reprint");
    menu.add(1, 2, 1, "Void");

    menu.getItem(0).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem clickedItem)
        {

            return true;
        }
    });

    menu.getItem(1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem clickedItem)
        {

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}